# CUDA: Matrix + Matrix, segmentation fault when printing solution matrix in host

Tags: matrix, cuda

I'm trying to make a simple operation of adding a matrix to another one in CUDA, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to check the resault, here's the code:

```
/* Includes, system */
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#define N 15000

/* DEVICE CODE */
__global__ void sumaMatrices(int *d_matrix1, int *d_matrix2, int *d_matrixSolucion){

    int idThread = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (idThread < N)
    {
        d_matrixSolucion[idThread] = d_matrix1[idThread] + d_matrix2[idThread];
    }
}

__host__ void printMatrix(int **matrix) 
{
    int i, j;
    //only 4 so the file is not too big
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("  ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* HOST CODE*/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;

    int **h_matrix1;
    int **h_matrix2;
    int **h_matrixSolucion;

    int *d_matrix1;
    int *d_matrix2;
    int *d_matrixSolucion;

    h_matrix1 = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        h_matrix1[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    }

    h_matrix2 = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        h_matrix2[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    }

    h_matrixSolucion = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        h_matrixSolucion[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)& d_matrix1,N*N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)& d_matrix2,N*N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)& d_matrixSolucion,N*N*sizeof(int));

    fillMatrix(h_matrix1);
    fillMatrix(h_matrix2);
    fillMatrixTo0(h_matrixSolucion);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        cudaMemcpy(&d_matrix1[i*N], h_matrix1[i], N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(&d_matrix2[i*N], h_matrix2[i], N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    int tamBloque = 256;
    int tamGrid = N/tamBloque + 1;
    sumaMatrices<<<tamGrid, tamBloque>>>(d_matrix1, d_matrix2, d_matrixSolucion);

    //nos traemos la información del device
cudaThreadSynchronize();
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
    cudaMemcpy(h_matrixSolucion[i], &d_matrixSolucion[i*N],tamGrid*sizeof(h_matrixSolucion[0]),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

    printMatrix(h_matrix1);
    printMatrix(h_matrix2);
    printMatrix(h_matrixSolucion);
}
```

If I comment that last line the progams doens't give any error.

I'm guesss the problem is that I don't storage the information properly in the kernel (this line: d_matrixSolucion[idThread] = d_matrix1[idThread] + d_matrix2[idThread];) but I am pretty new to CUDA and I don't really know how to solve it.

EDIT: Now that I've changed the way I get the information back from the device this is what is printing:

0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6

2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
4  5  6  7
5  6  7  8

2  4  6  8
0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0

The first 2 matrix are the ones with the information and the other one is the solution, but only has 1 line filled.

Comment: You need a loop for the `cudaMemcpy` operation when copying the results back to the host, just like you have a loop when copying the data to the device.  Your underlying host allocations are not guaranteed to be contiguous.  Also, `fillMatrix` is undefined in the code you have shown; it won't compile.

Comment: "Your underlying host allocations are not guaranteed to be contiguous". Is that why I am only getting the first line filled?

fillMatrix does indeed exist, I just didn't add to the code of the question because I thought it didn't add anytning, is just a function that fills the matrix with a random number.

Btw, I'd added some more info

Comment: no, there is another issue that is causing only the first line to be correct.  see my answer item 4.  And I didn't say "fillMatrix doesn't exist", I said that "fillMatrix is undefined in the code you have shown", which is an accurate statement.  When asking for debug assistance on SO, you are supposed to provide a [mcve], and the C (Complete) means that things like `fillMatrix` shouldn't be missing when you post a [mcve].  Anyway, why not include it in your posting?  You already have it, and it makes it easier for me to work on your code.  I actually want to compile and run your code.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I've just thoguht that as it is a really simple function it wouldn't be necessary to underestand the problem I was having, but I didn't realize that without that function it would be harder for anyone trying to help me to run my code, sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of errors in your code.

1. There was not definition for `fillMatrix`
2. Your underlying host allocations performed with `malloc` are not guaranteed to be contiguous, therefore you cannot transfer the data back in a single `cudaMemcpy` operation, but you must use a loop, like the loop you used to transfer data to the GPU
3. Your host allocations aren't quite right but they don't present an actual problem.  This:

   ```
   h_matrix1[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
   ```

   should be this:

   ```
   h_matrix1[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
   ```

   and likewise for the other similar instances.
4. Your grid (total number of threads) sizing is not correct.  Your kernel uses one thread to perform one elementwise addition.  Therefore, for a NxN matrix, you need NxN threads, not just N as you are creating and testing against.

The following code has these issues fixed and seems to work correctly for me:

```
$ cat t2.cu
/* Includes, system */
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#define N 15000

/* DEVICE CODE */
__global__ void sumaMatrices(int *d_matrix1, int *d_matrix2, int *d_matrixSolucion){

    int idThread = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (idThread < N*N)
    {
        d_matrixSolucion[idThread] = d_matrix1[idThread] + d_matrix2[idThread];
    }
}

__host__ void printMatrix(int **matrix)
{
    int i, j;
    //only 4 so the file is not too big
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("  ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* HOST CODE*/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;

    int **h_matrix1;
    int **h_matrix2;
    int **h_matrixSolucion;

    int *d_matrix1;
    int *d_matrix2;
    int *d_matrixSolucion;

    h_matrix1 = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        h_matrix1[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) h_matrix1[i][j] = 1;
    }

    h_matrix2 = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        h_matrix2[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) h_matrix2[i][j] = 2;
    }

    h_matrixSolucion = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        h_matrixSolucion[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) h_matrixSolucion[i][j] = 0;
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)& d_matrix1,N*N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)& d_matrix2,N*N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)& d_matrixSolucion,N*N*sizeof(int));


    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cudaMemcpy(&d_matrix1[i*N], h_matrix1[i], N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(&d_matrix2[i*N], h_matrix2[i], N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    int tamBloque = 256;
    int tamGrid = (N*N)/tamBloque + 1;
    sumaMatrices<<<tamGrid, tamBloque>>>(d_matrix1, d_matrix2, d_matrixSolucion);

    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cudaMemcpy(h_matrixSolucion[i],&d_matrixSolucion[i*N],N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }

    printMatrix(h_matrix1);
    printMatrix(h_matrix2);
    printMatrix(h_matrixSolucion);
}
$ nvcc -o t2 t2.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t2
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1

2  2  2  2
2  2  2  2
2  2  2  2
2  2  2  2

3  3  3  3
3  3  3  3
3  3  3  3
3  3  3  3

========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```